# Query ignoring text

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

When I share data with sub-subcontractors, I use the [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) function to return a subset based on a company name match. I never had any issues in the past, but lately [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) has not been returning values if they are text, only if they are numbers.

Also, Sheets' ["Fill Down"](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/181110?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=%2Cmac-shortcuts:%7E:text=%E2%8C%98%20%2B%20Enter-,Fill%20down,-%E2%8C%98%20%2B%20d) shortcut **<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>** has stopped working (MacBook Air).

Did I mess something up, or did something change?

**Example QUERY:**

```
=QUERY(
   IMPORTRANGE(spreadsheet_url, range_string),
   "select Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5, Col6, Col7,
      Col8, Col13, Col14, Col15 where Col5
      matches 'company_name'")
```

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). The problem is not really with the formula but with the data. Please [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/170809/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with another table that shows your _manually entered_ desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a safe [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform).

Comment: See @doubleunary's [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/170815/) vis-a-vis [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en).  With respect to executing the [`Fill Down`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/181110?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=%2Cmac-shortcuts:%7E:text=%E2%8C%98%20%2B%20Enter-,Fill%20down,-%E2%8C%98%20%2B%20d) command,  ensure you are selecting **only the target cell**  OR  **both the source and target cell**.   Selecting only the source cell will not work.

Answer (score 1):

> query have been ignoring data that includes text and not numbers

The `query()` function only accepts one data type per column. If you have a mix of text strings like `abc` and numbers like `123` in a column, one or the other type will be returned as nulls.

To get all data from columns that have mixed types, use `filter()`, like this:

```
=let( 
  data, importrange("DOCUMENT", "TAB!A:DK"), 
  filtered, filter(data, search("Company name", choosecols(data, 5))), 
  choosecols(filtered, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 13, 14, 15) 
)
```